# How to convert back to the default text of the textbox when user leave the textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently designing a sign-up form in c# Visual Studio and I encounter a problem. As you can see from the first picture, I have two textboxes with their own default text. After that, I created an enter and leave event handler for them.
**My goal** is When the user clicks onto the textbox, the default text will disappear and the user can begin to enter their password which will be replaced with asterisks. When the user leaves the textbox without inputting any value, the default text will be shown again. However, now my **problem** is that the default text will be converted to asterisk, which is not what i want. [image] [image]
Here is a sample of my code

```
  private void txtPassword_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword.Text == "Enter a password...")
        {
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*'; // Mask characters of a password to asterisk. 
            txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void txtPassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            txtPassword.Text = "Enter a password...";
            txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the `PasswordChar` in order to stop the textbox from masking the text.
Your `Leave` event handler should look like this:

```
private void txtPassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtPassword.Text == "")
    {
        txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0'; // Note this line!
        txtPassword.Text = "Enter a password...";
        txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that works!! Thank you so much!! Btw, may I know what does \0 means?

Comment: '\0' is a "null character"